# Grub shown for the only system

Tags: grub, kubuntu

I've been having Kubuntu 18.04 for a while. After that I installed Kubuntu 19.04 over previous (I changed disk part settings to create volume that can be encrypted thus there is no Kubuntu 18.04 anymore).

However, after I installed Kubuntu 19.04 I started seeing grub menu on every boot. There is only one system to be chosen and I cannot understand menu is shown for me.

Is there a way to fix this? I've tried to update grub list but have the same result so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your `/etc/default/grub` file and change the line with `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`.

If there is no such entry, just add it.

For information, on how to edit your `/etc/default/grub`, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#A.2Fetc.2Fdefault.2Fgrub).